# How to grab raw buffer from bitmap in GDI?

Tags: c, gdi

If I understand GDI correctly then the function `GetDIBits` retreives the raw pixel data from a captured bitmap image in windows

> The GetDIBits function retrieves the bits of the specified compatible bitmap and copies them into a buffer as a DIB using the specified format.

so the following code should grab the pixel data only

```
    HDC srcd , memdc;
    HBITMAP hbmp;
    BITMAP bmp;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    char* lpbitmap = NULL;
    HANDLE hDIB = NULL;
    DWORD dwBmpSize = 0;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;
    int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);

    srcd = GetDC(NULL); 
    if (!srcd)
        printf("failed to obtain screen");
    
    memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(srcd); // creates memory device context 
    hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcd, Width, Height);
    SelectObject(memdc, hbmp);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, srcd, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(bmpScreen), (LPVOID)&bmpScreen);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    lpbitmap = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    GetDIBits(memdc, hbmp, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    printf("dwBmpSize: %ld\n", dwBmpSize);
    printf("Strlen(lpbitmap): %lld\n", strlen(lpbitmap));
```

In my case I have a single screen with size (1920,1080) with a 32 bit value for each pixel then I should have around 66 mega bits but the output that I get does not make sense

```
dwBmpSize: 8294400
Strlen(lpbitmap): 103614
```

with that said I have couple of confusions:

- Why does `strlen` return this small number
- Why does the `lpbitmap` buffer contain garbage values (mostly A letters)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `strlen` return this small number?

The `strlen` function is for textual strings, not bitmap data. This is binary data. The `strlen` simply reports the offset of where the first 0 value is found (usually the string terminator).

> Why does the `lpbitmap` buffer contain garbage values (mostly A letters)?

None of the data is garbage. If you see a lot of one particular value, it is probably the background colour of the image you grabbed. It is meaningless when viewed with a text editor.